# On Linux system, Other than using "cgroups" is there any way to limit running process' memory usage?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

Example,

A process is consuming 200MB, Is there any way to restrict its usage only to 100MB without using cgroup. (Remaining 100MB it can use from swap space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to do this with `ulimit -m`.  That restricts the maximum resident set.  However, the manual entry states that a lot of systems don't honor (i.e. implement) this limit.  Note that the limits set this way only apply to new processes started by the current shell.  (The ulimit command is a shell built-in command.)

Alternatively, the `prlimit` command allows you to alter the resource limits for an existing process.

Comment: For the Linux system, [This limit has         effect only in Linux 2.4.x, x < 30, and there affects only              calls to madvise(2) specifying MADV_WILLNEED.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prlimit.2.html)